# Generating URL with CSRF token

Tags: 8, csrf

I have a route that requires a CSRF token:

```
mp.ajax.authorized:
  path: /mp/ajax/authorized
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\mp\Controller\AjaxController::authorizedCallback'
  requirements:
    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
```

I need to generate a URL for this route. As the route has _csrf_token set to TRUE, the route needs to contain a CSRF token.

I've generated a URL from the route using Url:

```
Url::fromRoute('mp.ajax.authorized', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString()
```

It generates a route with a token:

```
http://example.com/mp/ajax/authorized?token=91018d3f93299fe116c5596ea32d9addca063a92
```

I also tried the url_generator service to generate the URL:

```
$url_generator = \Drupal::service('url_generator');
$url = $url_generator->generateFromRoute('mp.ajax.authorized', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
```

And it generates the same URL.

However, the token on the URL is incorrect, as the actual CSRF token that is retrieved from CsrfTokenGenerator is:

```
1qG-Tw4AyQgNmVWtlkp_to7mielSz8ZfQZAkhWqAlsQ
```

I've done some reading, and it appears that the token given from Url is a placeholder, but I need the actual token, not the placeholder. Does anyone know how to get this?

Update: I've discovered I can retrieve the URL with a token in it by passing token as a parameter to the Url builder:

```
Url::fromRoute('mp.ajax.authorized', [], ['absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => ['token' => \Drupal::csrfToken()->get()]])->toString()
```

However, this token fails validation in Drupal\Core\Access\CsrfAccessCheck, so it appears this is not the correct solution.

Comment: Could this be related to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2670798? I think it's worth checking, since you're using 'ajax' in the path; that could cause it to face the same problem as ajaxified links (those get 'nojs' converted to 'ajax').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a solution, however, I'd be amazed if there isn't a better way to do it, and in fact I'm pretty sure it's bypassing the placeholder API, so it's likely the wrong way to do it. But until someone gives me a better solution, it's a working one.

The solution is to generate the token manually, then set it as a GET query on the URL when generating the URL.

When generating the token however, you need the internal path for the route, which is used as a basis for generating the token.

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('mp.ajax.authorized');
$token = \Drupal::csrfToken()->get($url->getInternalPath());
$url->setOptions(['absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => ['token' => $token]]);
$absolute_url = $url->toString()
```

Note that I've already found this method doesn't work on routes with optional parameters, so if someone comes across this, you'll have to find another method in such a case.

Comment: Just ran into this issue again - still stuck on how to do it with optional parameters.

Comment: any update on this? also the answer above with optional parameters wont work

Comment: i get csrf_token URL query argument is invalid even for route without parameters

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code of Jaypan but with additional parameter (node id):

**routing.yml:**

```
entity.node.publish:
  path: '/node/{node}/toggleStatus'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\publishcontent\Controller\PublishContentPublishEntity::toggleEntityStatus'
  requirements:
    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
    _publish_access_check: 'TRUE'
```

**custom function:**

```
$nid = 100;
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.publish', ['node' => $nid]);
$token = \Drupal::csrfToken()->get($url->getInternalPath());
$url->setOptions(['absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => ['token' => $token]]);
$absolute_url = $url->toString();
```

Will return something like this:

```
https://www.exapmle.com/node/100/toggleStatus?token=PF06yJ7PLR052_HxeTWvsuye88d7NAZgwanN3yiswU
```